# How to stop the wordninja library removing sentence punctuation

Tags: python, nlp

I am using `wordninja.split()` from the [wordninja](https://pypi.org/project/wordninja/2.0.0/) Python package to separate munged together sentences, however, it's also removing full stops from the sentences too. How can I prevent this behavior? I want to retain the full stops in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Preservation of punctuation was added with commit [b3120f0](https://github.com/keredson/wordninja/commit/b3120f00f0ea53e6927cd2cc60bc77894c7ff36e), however, presently the [PyPI version](https://pypi.org/project/wordninja/2.0.0/) installed with pip is not up-to-date with the GitHub repository.

To manually add this feature, locate the `wordninja` module installation directory:

```
pip show wordninja
```

Navigate to the directory listed in the output from the above command, and then edit the `split` function within the `wordninja.py` file to be:

```py
def split(self, s):
    """Uses dynamic programming to infer the location of spaces in a string without spaces."""
    punctuations = _SPLIT_RE.findall(s)
    texts = _SPLIT_RE.split(s)
    assert len(punctuations) + 1 == len(texts)
    new_texts = [self._split(x) for x in texts]
    for i, punctuation in enumerate(punctuations):
      new_texts.insert(2*i+1, punctuation)
    return [item for sublist in new_texts for item in sublist]
```

Instead of:

```py
def split(self, s):
    """Uses dynamic programming to infer the location of spaces in a string without spaces."""
    l = [self._split(x) for x in _SPLIT_RE.split(s)]
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

#### Test code

```py
import wordninja

text = "This isasentence. I am trying to splitthesewords."
split_text = wordninja.split(text)
print(split_text)
```

Output before updating the `split` function:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'I', 'am', 'trying', 'to', 'split', 'these', 'words']
```

Output after updating the`split` function:

```
['This', ' ', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'am', ' ', 'trying', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'split', 'these', 'words', '.']
```

You'll have to manually handle white-space and punctuation in the list after enabling this feature.